# MySQL Buscar registros que no son iguales

Tags: mysql

Hola buen dia tengo 2 tablas que muestro en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo utiliz esta consulta

```
select a.rpu from costas a left join 
referencia b on b.rpu_ref = a.rpu where b.rpu_ref is null
```

Para tener de resultado de busqueda que la tabla costas que rpu de referencia no son iguales y me sale este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero hacer es que no nada mas salga el campo rpu si no tambien el campo de nombre que se encuentra en la tabla referencia.

Gracias

Comment: No creo estar entendiendo lo que necesitas, pero quiero aclarar lo que creo que entendí. Primero la consulta con un `left join` devuelve el mismo resultado que la consulta con subconsulta `where not exists` que muestras, pero no es la misma consulta, y por lo tanto no accede al atributo `b.nombre` que quieres, es así?. Por otro lado, como bien dices (si te entiendo bien) la consulta devuelve los RPU que "no son iguales" (dígase, no se encuentran) en la tabla `Referencia`, cito: `b.rpu_ref is null` (equivalente a "No logró hacer el join") y por lo tanto b.nombre tambien será null.

Answer (score 0):

> Bastaría con que a tu consulta le agregues después de a.rpu una coma y
>   la columna b.nombre ya después todo lo demás quedaría igual

```
select a.rpu, b.nombre from costas a left join 
referencia b on b.rpu_ref = a.rpu where b.rpu_ref is null;
```

**El demás orden se mantiene puesto que ya esta la instrucción left join**

Ahora si notas que quieres valores que no esten repetidos, agregale el operador DISTINCT para traer valores únicos

```
select distinct a.rpu, b.nombre from costas a left join 
    referencia b on b.rpu_ref = a.rpu where b.rpu_ref is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

qué tal.

¿Has intentado con la cláusula DISTINCT?

SELECT DISTINCT campo FROM tabla;

Saludos.